# Can't set chrome preferences in vba selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've created a script in vba in combination with selenium to parse the first headline from [this webpage](https://www.marketscreener.com/). Most of the times my script throws this error `timeout` or this error `Run-time error 21; Application defined or Object defined error` while sometimes it works flawlessly. As the page takes too much time to load it's content, I suppose I'm having one of the side effect of a slow loading page, so I wish to disable images from that page.

I've tried with:

```
Sub TestSelenium()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.marketscreener.com/"
    Dim driver As Object, post As Object
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver

    driver.get URL
    Set post = driver.FindElementByCss(".une_title")
    MsgBox post.Text
    driver.Quit
End Sub
```

When I go for python selenium binding, I can use this option to disable images:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```

I know there are options to set different preferences in vba but in case of disabling images I can't find any proper way to set them:

```
driver.SetPreference
driver.AddArgument
```

***How can I set chrome preferences in vba selenium to let the page load quickly without images?***

Answer (score 1):

To disable images from that page, this is how you can set the preference within vba selenium bindings:

```
driver.SetPreference "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2
```

Your script looks like the following when you implement the above suggestion:

```
Sub TestSelenium()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.marketscreener.com/"
    Dim driver As Object, post As Object
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver

    driver.SetPreference "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2
    driver.get URL
    Set post = driver.FindElementByCss(".une_title")
    MsgBox post.Text
    Stop
    driver.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try running it headless? That should remove any delay associated with image loading.

```
driver.AddArgument "--headless"
```